# Refused to execute script runtime.js because MIME type is not executable

Tags: javascript, html, angular, spring-boot, angular-cli

This is the error I'm getting when performed browser inspect -> Console tab of index.html file.

> Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:63342/runtime.js'
>   because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME
>   type checking is enabled.

My app is an integration of spring-boot and Angular. **I believe this is also the cause for spring-boot not serving the frontend js and .html file content on UI.** Although backend application works fine but on tomcat service start, it doesn't show any UI on http://localhost:8080.

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node:10.0.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 6.1.7
```

The generated index.html has  tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

Changing type manually to "text/html" resolves the error, but still doesn't show anything on UI. 
Is this an issue due to particular angular-cli version? Are my two issues (spring not serving frontend static resources) related? Or is base href wrong?
Is there a way to not resolve this without manually changing the type in script tag? Because index.html gets generated on running `ng build`  and gets placed in resources directory. And I'm doing this to make deployment easier. Here is the whole generated index.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Welcome App</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

I am a new bee in this, please provide help.

This is what I see in browser inspect -> Network -> Headers (When open the file from browser option in Intellij and tomcat isn't running).
Response header for one of the generated angular file:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
content-type: text/html
server: IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.2
date: Sun, 16 Sep 2018 16:08:39 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SameOrigin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

But when tomcat is up and running,notice 200 response on inspect :

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

Since its app/json and I see [ ] in response, which I think is wrong and should have been an html response.

**Are these script tags that gets added on ng build in index.html an issue for not showing the content on UI or something else?** I didn't think so because I copy pasted my static content in a demo gradle project(from  https://start.spring.io/) and it shows UI on webpage so changing 'text/javascript' to 'html' isn't really an issue I believe; but not sure. And this is what I see in  response for working UI:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10325#issuecomment-399329033)?

Comment: Your web server is sending javascript files with the wrong mime type. Paste the response's contentType header.

Comment: @Rafael thanks for reply. I edited the post (at the bottom) to put the response headers .
Note: this pasted response header is before changing the script type to "text/html". So currently its "text/javascript"

Comment: @SoC Changing the `type` attribute of the `<script>` tag will achieve nothing. You will need to reconfigure your server so that it serves the `.js` files with the `content-type: text/javascript` HTTP header.

Comment: @Bergi I agree with you and that's why put my similar thoughts in post. However, I'm not sure what or how to reconfigure the server to serve .js files .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache2, check apache2.conf in /etc/apache2/

Make sure you have this line:

AddType text/javascript .js

Make sure mod:mime is installed and enabled:

sudo a2enmod mime